# .Net Remoting server dll in same directory as the executable

Tags: remoting

I have an application that hosts a remote object. For the client application to access this remote object; the dll with the remote server implemented, should be in the same directory where the executable of the server application resides. When I install this application the dll resides in a different directory and I manually paste the dll to the same directory where the server executable resides.

I do not want to do this every time. Is there a way to get around this problem? That is the application refer the dll from where it is available rather than demanding the dll to be in the same directory where the executable resides.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30601&seqNum=6